# Expiring complex data types in Redis

Tags: redis

I'm currently using Redis as a cache for my web-application. I'm planning on storing some complex data-types like objects with multiple attributes. Now I know hashes are made for just this purpose in Redis, but I'd like to expire the keys in the hashes at some point, which isn't possible in Redis. It seems you can only expire stand-alone keys. Does anyone have an alternative solution? My only solution so far was to store the mapping of the data as a JSON object in the key, with the data as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPIRE command on HSET to achieve this objective.
Can you elaborate with an example of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Check https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redis-db/44NWMLanGdI
using ZSET

With this you expire non-key elements as well
Unfortunately its not straighforward